# Windows 10 - SYN/ACK packet not sent in response to SYN packets

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I tried to run a simple 1-page site with Flask in Python on port 5000 of my computer `192.168.0.113`, which is running Windows 10. On the same computer, I can view the site by using `localhost:5000` in a web browser.

I tried to use another computer `192.168.0.134` on the same LAN to view the site. However, `192.168.0.113` never replied with a `SYN/ACK` packet to the `SYN` packet from `192.168.0.134`, even if the firewall of `192.168.0.113` is completely turned off. This image is the captured flow of the packets:

[image]

If I did it reversely (i.e. `192.168.0.134` as the server to host the site, and `192.168.0.113` tried to connect as the client), then `192.168.0.113` is able to connect.

I noted from some previous posts (especially [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/235965/why-would-a-server-not-send-a-syn-ack-packet-in-response-to-a-syn-packet)) that the problem can be solved by disabling TCP window scaling and TCP timestamps. I checked in `netsh` of `192.168.0.113` and noted that TCP window scaling had already been `disabled` and TCP timestamps was `normal`. I tried to disable both of them, and also tried to disable just one of them. However, all combinations failed and `192.168.0.113` still wonn't sent `SYN/ACK` packets in response to `SYN` packets from `192.168.0.134`.

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: What address did you bind to?  `0.0.0.0:5000` or `127.0.0.1:5000` ?

Comment: Also, on the same computer where `localhost:5000` works also try `192.168.0.113:5000`

Comment: hi, I just used `192.168.0.134` to `ping 192.168.0.113`, and 113 is able to reply the ICMP packets to 134 (10 request v.s. 8 reply).

Comment: For browser of `192.168.0.113`, the `localhost:5000` works, but `192.168.0.113:5000` shows "This site can’t be reached" error.

Comment: That indicates you are binding to only the localhost interface instead of all local IP addresses.  Change your `bind()` call.

Comment: @BenVoigt I should go to `Network Connections` -> `Advanced Settings` to change the bind call, right? I think normally speaking there should be 2 tabs of "Adapters and Bindings" and "Provider Order" from the image that I obtained from web, but now I just have 1 tab of "provider order", in which it states "failed to get network providers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More broadly you are only showing traffic going in one direction in the Wireshark capture.

You probably are not listening on an external IP addresses. The Flask application takes an IP address argument to listen on, if it is `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it will not respond to external connection. Set this to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all IP addresses. Verify this by running the command `netstat -a -b` to see which IP address you application is listening on.

The Flask [Quick start](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/) page goes through this (see Externally Visible Server)

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Many thanks. I think I'm showing both direction as I used `ip.addr` instead of `ip.dst` or `ip.src`?

I tried to run `python -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0` in `cmd`, and I got "could not locate Flask application. You did not provide the Flask_App environment variable." I tried to run `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` in Python, and got wrong syntax... I'm still trying to work it out...

Comment: I finally got it done, many thanks! I run this in my Python code: `app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=int("5000"),debug=True)`, where app is defined as `app = Flask(__name__)` in the previous line.